# exporting default function react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm just learning React Native, and in the basic examples I just have a single class that extends Component and is the dafault export.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  // code
}
```

This works well, and I have no problem.

But I've found other examples, where they provide the code as a function.

```
export const App = () => {
  // code
}
```

As I see this function is called App and is exported, however if I try to run it (I use expo) I get the following Message

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

Not sure about the error, since the function App is exported (maybe the error comes from not being the default export)?

How can I fix this?

Comment: found it, just need to add the line `export default App;` at the end of the file, so the function App gets exported as default

Answer (score 2):

If its a default export

```
export default class App extends Component {
  // code
}
```

Import it like this

```
import App from "./Apppath"
```

If its not a default export or named export (one with not a default keyword)

```
export const App = () => {
  // code
}
```

Import it like

```
 import {App} from "./Apppath"
```

See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: App.js is my main file, where should I import App? Expo directly goes to App.js and executes the default class, but in this case is a function

Comment: probably in index.js ? @SembeiNorimaki

Comment: Ok I solved it. I just need to add the line `export default App;` at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You have not make default export for App component. In this case you need to use below line
import { App } from '..'